# How to access or extend any public class in web application, which is defined in Other project for window services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, wcf

In my solution Explorer I have two Project one for windows service EnterpriseIQ.Service And the other Project EnterpriseIQ for Web Application.

My problem: I want to access Class defined inside Windows service project, from my Web App.[This is my solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnhiD.png) I want to access Taskmanager.cs class from WebApp

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You might want to have a go at adding a little detail to your question. You might find this page useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Yes, define the class as `public` in `Taskmanager.cs` like

```
public class Taskmanager { ... }
```

Add the `windows service EnterpriseIQ` project reference in your `EnterpriseIQ for Web Application` project. Also, add/import the proper namespace in which `Taskmanager` class is defined.

Comment: In addition to Rahul's instructions, whenever you have classes consumed by multiple applications, it's also a good idea to see if you can start breaking those shared classes into their own class library, then consume that library by both your projects. That way you don't have a web applciation dependent on functionality from the windows service dll and they can be maintained in a cleaner fashion.